# Integral Convergence $\sin{x}/x^{3/2}$

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

Does the following integral converge:

$$\int_0^\infty{\frac{\sin x}{x^{3/2}}}dx$$

I have tried to integrate this by parts and arrived at:

$$-x^{-3/2}\cos x -\int \frac 12{x^{-1/2}}\cos{x} dx $$

Which equals:

$$-x^{-3/2}\cos x -\int \cos{u^2}du$$

I then tried to use the Freshnel Integral for Cos however arrived at an answer that wasn't anywhere close to what Wolfram Alpha provided which was:

$\sqrt{2}\pi$

If anyone could help with this problem it would be great.

Comment: Recall absolute convergence implies convergence. This will make the problem much easier. I'd handle $\int_0^1,\int_1^\infty$ separately.

Comment: the right result is $$\sqrt{2\pi}$$

Answer (score 2):

If $0<x<1$ we have
$$
0<\frac{\sin x}{x^{3/2}}< \frac{1}{x^{1/2}}\quad\text{and}\quad\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x^{1/2}}<\infty\text{ since }1/2<1.
$$
On the other hand
$$
\Bigl|\frac{\sin x}{x^{3/2}}\Bigr|\le\frac{1}{x^{3/2}}\quad\text{and}\quad\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{x^{3/2}}<\infty\text{ since }3/2>1.
$$

Answer (score 0):

The integral converges. First of all
$${\sin(x)\over x^p}\sim {x\over x^p} = {1\over x^{p-1}}$$
as $x\to 0$;
this integrates at zero if and only if $p - 1 < 1$ or if $p  <2$.  Your integrand in fact has an integrable discontinuity there.  Disregard the first two humps so we don't have to do any work there. After that the rest decrease in area, bobbing above and below the $x$-axis.  Now you can see that the  integral converges by the alternating series test.

Comment: Actually, the discontinuity is not removable since $\frac{\sin x}{x^{3/2}}=O(x^{-1/2})$.  But both the improper Riemann integral and the Lebesgue integral $\int_0^1x^{-1/2}dx$ exist.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{\sin x}{x^{3/2}}$ has an integrable singularity in a right neighbourhood of the origin, where $\sin x\sim x$.
On the other hand, [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) gives that $\frac{\sin x}{x^{3/2}}$ is improperly Riemann integrable over $[1,+\infty)$, since $\sin x$ has a bounded primitive and $\frac{1}{x^{3/2}}$ decreases to zero on that interval.

Moreover, since $\mathcal{L}(\sin x)=\frac{1}{1+s^2}$ and $\mathcal{L}^{-1}(x^{-3/2})=2\sqrt{\frac{s}{\pi}}$,
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x^{3/2}}\,dx = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sqrt{s}}{1+s^2}\,ds=\frac{4}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{t^2}{1+t^4}\,dt=\color{red}{\sqrt{2\pi}}.$$

Comment: Hi Jack thanks for your answer, could you explain how you move from the 2nd to last integral using s into the integral using t?

Comment: @MWTDeeks: I replaced $s$ with $t^2$.

Comment: root(s) = t surely if s is replaced with t^2? Which then leads to my question as to where the 4 comes from?

Comment: @MWTDeeks: do you know how to perform a substitution in a integral? $s=t^2$ leads to $ds = 2t\,dt$.

Comment: Ah sorry, blip in my mind there. Ofcourse it is.