# Curious improper integral:$\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\dfrac{\sin(x^3)}{x^2}dx$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, gamma-function

I found the following integral, $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\dfrac{\sin(x^3)}{x^2}dx$ which at first seemed quite curious to me, but although I tried several times I couldn't get anything. I know it's convergent thanks to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5Bsin%5C%2840%29Power%5Bx%2C3%5D%5C%2841%29%2CPower%5Bx%2C2%5D%5D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C%E2%88%9E%7D%5D&lang=es). I'm surprised that WolframAlpha tells me that the integral turns out to be $\dfrac{\Gamma(2/3)}{2}$. I have also tried to use [Maz identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1373796/integral-convergence-sinx-x3-2), without any success. Any ideas please.

Comment: Does Jack Aurizio’s method in the post you linked not work? You get $\frac13\int_0^\infty u^{-4/3}\sin u\,du$ with the obvious substitution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $y=x^3$, then the integral is transformed into a Gamma function.
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\frac{1}{3} \int_0^{\infty} y^{-\frac{4}{3}} \sin y d y \\
& =-\frac{1}{3} \Im\int_0^{\infty} y^{-\frac{1}{3}-1} e^{-y i} d y \\
& =-\frac{1}{3} \Im\left[\frac{\Gamma\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)}{i^{-\frac{1}{3}}}\right] \\
& =\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{3}\right) \operatorname{Im}\left(e^{\frac{\pi}{2} i}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} \\
& =\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)}{2}
\end{aligned}
$$
where the last line using $\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)=\Gamma\left(1+\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)\right)=-\frac{1}{3} \Gamma\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right).$

Answer (score 2):

As @Lai commented, using integration by parts with $u=\sin(x^3)$

$$\int\dfrac{\sin(x^3)}{x^2}dx=-\frac{\sin \left(x^3\right)}{x}+3 \int x \cos \left(x^3\right)\,dx$$

Using the exponential integral function
$$\int x \cos \left(x^3\right)\,dx=-\frac{1}{2} x^2 \left(E_{\frac{1}{3}}\left(+i
   x^3\right)+E_{\frac{1}{3}}\left(-i x^3\right)\right)$$

You could also use the incomplete gamma function.

Using the bounds, the result.